# SQL - select values that match several of 3 combined conditions

Tags: mysql, select

after trying to solve this problem and unsuccessfully scouring the web for answers, I am resigned to seeking help - so any will be greatly appreciated!

I have a SQL table with the following structure:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(25)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| municipality | varchar(50) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| admin        | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country      | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude    | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| latitude     | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and I wish to **SELECT** a subset of this table where a several triplets of conditions are met, e.g.  : 
`municipality = 'New York', admin = 'New York', country = 'United States'`. I wish to do this and select not only on `municipality` because on occasion, identical placenames exist in different administrative areas.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (municipality, admin, country) IN 
('Pearl River', 'New York', 'United States'), 
('Shelton', 'Washington', 'United States'), 
('Granite', 'Illinois', 'United States'), 
('Washington', 'Pennsylvania', 'United States'), 
('Erlanger', 'Kentucky', 'United States'), 
('Warren', 'Ohio', 'United States');
```

as well as:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE municipality IN ('Pearl River', 'Shelton', 'Granite', 'Washington', 'Erlanger', 'Warren') 
AND WHERE admin IN ('New York', 'Washington', 'Illinois', 'Pennsylvania', 'Kentucky', 'Ohio') 
AND WHERE country IN ('United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States');
```

but both queries only return this standard error: `could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

I really hope someone can help me with this, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Correct syntax is `WHERE (x,y.z) IN (('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'))` or `WHERE x IN('a', 'b', 'c') AND y IN ('c', 'd', 'e') AND z IN ('f', 'g', 'h')`.

Comment: hi @PaulSpiegel - thanks so much for your response. do you mean ```WHERE (x, y, z)``` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I mean `(x,y,z)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should surround your list of tuples against which you are matching with parentheses and prefix them with "VALUES". E.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (municipality, admin, country) IN (
    VALUES 
        ('Pearl River', 'New York', 'United States'), 
        ('Pearl', 'New York', 'United States'), 
        ('Athens', 'Georgia', 'United States')
);
```

I've tested this against a sqlite database with the following structure and get the correct output back, I think.

```
CREATE TABLE locations (municipality TEXT, admin TEXT, country TEXT);
INSERT INTO locations VALUES('Pearl River','New York','United States');
INSERT INTO locations VALUES('Pearl River','Alabama','United States');
INSERT INTO locations VALUES('Athens','Georgia','United States');
```

Returns the following:

```
Pearl River|New York|United States
Athens|Georgia|United States
```

-- NINJA EDIT --

Note that the above query works in SQLite but not in MySQL. To make this query work for MySQL, simply remove the "VALUES" keyword, but it is critical that you keep the parentheses around your list of tuples. E.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (municipality, admin, country) IN (
        ('Pearl River', 'New York', 'United States'), 
        ('Pearl', 'New York', 'United States'), 
        ('Athens', 'Georgia', 'United States')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM locations WHERE municipality IN ('Pearl River', 'Shelton', 'Granite', 'Washington', 'Erlanger', 'Warren') 
AND admin IN ('New York', 'Washington', 'Illinois', 'Pennsylvania', 'Kentucky', 'Ohio') 
AND country IN ('United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States');

Once WHERE is enough.

Comment: hi @Pavithra, thanks so much for your answer! on the plus side, it did return something, so that's cool. however, it didn't return matches for *all 3* conditions, but rather any match for any of the 3 conditions combined. I.e. it has an entry for `Washington, PA`, `Washington, NY` and `Washington, KY`, even though I only want `Washington, PA`

Comment: What result is expected?

Comment: This query should return records matching all three conditions because it AND condition. Can you explain me the result needed.?

Comment: hi @Pavithra - so it's basically capturing any combination of condition 1, 2, and 3. but i only want the individual combinations. So, the first answer results in all entries for Pearl River, but I'm only interested in Pearl River, New York.

Comment: The above code works                                                                            
    SELECT * FROM locations WHERE (municipality, admin, country) IN (
    VALUES 
        ('Pearl River', 'New York', 'United States'), 
('Shelton', 'Washington', 'United States'), 
('Granite', 'Illinois', 'United States'), 
('Washington', 'Pennsylvania', 'United States'), 
('Erlanger', 'Kentucky', 'United States'), 
('Warren', 'Ohio', 'United States')
);